# Marlin firmware - integrating touchscreen on ender 3

Tags: makefile, firmware, platformio, 3d-printing

I am struggling to integrate the touchscreen in custom edited marlin firmware

The display is already flashed with DWIN and I've got this far:

- built the bin file and flashed it on the printer board (4.2.7 silent mb)
- the touch screen is responsive and I can shuffle through the menu

Problems:

- the text (en language) is not displayed on the bmps shown on the display
- when I blindly (intuitively tapping on pictograms because no text is shown on them lol) feed commands to the printer, nothing happens

Configuration.h changes:

1. `//#define CR10_STOCKDISPLAY` (commented stock display)
2. `#define DGUS_LCD_UI_FYSETC` (removed comment for that specific display - don't know if it's the right display but I found it in a DWIN set of displays)
3. 

```
// Show the Marlin bootscreen on startup. ** ENABLE FOR PRODUCTION **
//#define SHOW_BOOTSCREEN

// Show the bitmap in Marlin/_Bootscreen.h on startup.
//#define SHOW_CUSTOM_BOOTSCREEN

// Show the bitmap in Marlin/_Statusscreen.h on the status screen.
//#define CUSTOM_STATUS_SCREEN_IMAGE
```

(commented bootscreen, custom bootscreen and status screen definitions)

Display link: https://store.creality.com/products/ender-3-touch-screen
Marlin version: 2.1.2.1
Config template: Creality -> Ender-3 -> CrealityV427

Answer (score 0):

through lots of playing around i managed to get something to work

1. flashed DWIN 3.5 onto the display from https://github.com/CR6Community/CR-6-touchscreen/releases/tag/Re-Factored_v1.1 and placing DGUS2 kernel/T5L_UI_DGUS2_V35_20200730.BIN onto an SD in a folder called DWIN_SET
2. uploaded firmware to display from https://github.com/InsanityAutomation/Marlin/tree/CrealityDwin_2.0 using this file CombinedLandscapeDwin_TM3D_V8.7z placing the DWIN_SET folder on the SD card removing everything from step 1
3. compiled marlin bugfix-2.1.x with the following options in `Configuration.h`. Note started from the https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/tree/import-2.1.x/config/examples/Creality/Ender-3/CrealityV427

> #define DGUS_LCD_UI IA_CREALITY
>
> //#define CR10_STOCKDISPLAY
>
> #define CLASSIC_JERK
>
> #define NOZZLE_PARK_FEATURE

4. edited to following options in `Configuration_adv.h`

> #define ADVANCED_PAUSE_FEATURE

im sure there are other sources for these files but was happy to get it working. only thing, can only get it to work in landscape mode. the LCD_SCREEN_ROTATE did not display properly.

hope this help if you find out more post back